# google maps API v3 how do I remove arrow under the infowindow rectangle?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Is it possible to remove arrow under infowindow rectangle?

[image]

I really don't see need to include it here, I just want to center rectangle on the top of marker without arrow.

Possible?

Comment: @DavidChase I'd like to remove arrow not corners.

Comment: you can't customize the standard infowindow, but you can replace it with a third party infowindow (like infoBox described in that post), which does allow customization... (look at the InfoBox examples)

Comment: yes if you go to the link that is in the answer of that question you will see InfoBox example its yellow you cant miss it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible although long winded.

```
this.map.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="iw_content">' + contentString + '</div>'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(this.map.infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    el = document.getElementById('iw_content').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    el.firstChild.setAttribute('class', 'closeInfoWindow');
    el.firstChild.setAttribute('title', 'Close Info Window');
    el = el.previousElementSibling || el.previousSibling;
    el.setAttribute('class', 'infoWindowBackground');
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i = i + 1) {
        el = el.previousElementSibling || el.previousSibling;
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

That sets up anchors and hooks in the code that you can then use to style some of the infowindow but more inportantly, the last piece (the loop) will get rid of the arrow pieces.

It relies on the info window containing a div of 'iw_content' so it knows where to start from. Obviously you can change that, but that may require slight differences to the parent numbers. You should be able to work it out from that though.

Comment: not work now in 2017

Comment: Undocumented / ugly / bad and not working solution.