# How can I display an InfoWindow beyond the edge of a Google Map and not pan the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm using google maps api v3.
I'm displaying InfoWindow,and we know that unless auto-pan is disabled, an InfoWindow will pan the map to make itself visible when it is opened.

But i want to make the infowindow is fully visible when it opens with out pan the map,like intelligently switch the position and dimensions of the InfoWindow depending on where the edge is.

Maybe some would suggest [smartinfowindow](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html), but there is some problems with smartinfowindow,you can test it.

Is there any other way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: check the proposed solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404948/preventing-google-maps-move-after-displaying-infowindow/18410408#18410408

Comment: Thank you very much!It hepls a lot.I have worked it out with the infobox library.