# Obtain InfoWindow dimensions to pan map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to obtain this behaviour with Google Maps:

When a user clicks a Marker on a MapView, the InfoWindow is displayed with location details.  If the InfoWindow is not fully on screen, for example, the Marker is close to the screen edge of the map, pan the map enough to make the InfoWindow fully visible.

The problem I'm having is in being able to get the dimensions of the InfoWindow.  If I can obtain these I could do the calculations to pan.  Is this possible or is there a method to determine these values?

Comment: Maybe you could just center the map to the spot where InfoWindow is displayed? `map.moveCamera(...)`

Comment: if only.  however i'm constrained by use case.  :(

Comment: For `auto pan the map`, [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/32141) may help you. For `fully display the infoWindow without pan map`, please check with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404948/preventing-google-maps-move-after-displaying-infowindow/18410408#18410408)